# Mudar src de uma imagem baseado em ação na página anterior

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, preciso de ajuda para fazer o seguinte pq não estou conseguindo de jeito nenhum: Ao clicar em um botão (por exemplo) preciso ir para uma outra página. Até aí ok. Preciso nessa página que a imagem a ser exibida seja substituida por um link especifico.

Exemplo: ao clicar no botão jujuba.. vai para a pagina doces e substitua o src da imagem `id="doces_img"` para o `src="jujuba.png"`

de preferencia js. se precisar msm usar um framework, jquery. 
pensei em talvez criar uma variavel e mudar o valor dela daí quando a pagina "doces" carregar, ela vai verificar a variavel e substituir o src para o desejado. mas se for isso preciso que seja armazenado em cachê.

Comment: pode usar coockies

Comment: Use o local storage do html5

Comment: Ou você tem de usar **cookies**, **local storage** ou em último caso mas acredito que não fica nem um pouco bacana seria passar algum identificador na URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentado, uma boa solução é usar o `LocalStorage`, de uma olhada: https://jsfiddle.net/oy0vf3ng/1/

Para preservar o código:

HTML

```
<button id="btnJujuba" type="button" src-img-dinamica="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-07/29/10/enhanced/webdr15/enhanced-16875-1438181730-13.jpg">
  jujuba
</button>

<hr />

<img id="imgDinamica" src="http://galaxy.mobity.net/uploads/148/logo/1399898656.png" />
```

JS

```
var btnJujuba = document.querySelector('#btnJujuba');

btnJujuba.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var srcImgDinamica = this.getAttribute('src-img-dinamica');

    window.localStorage.setItem('srcImgDinamica', srcImgDinamica);

    loadImgDinamica();
});

function loadImgDinamica() {
    var imgDinamica = document.querySelector('#imgDinamica');

    var srcImgDinamica = window.localStorage.getItem('srcImgDinamica');

    if(srcImgDinamica) {
        imgDinamica.setAttribute('src', srcImgDinamica);
    }
}
```

O método `loadImgDinamica()` é para simular a troca de página, ou seja, no lugar dele você faz o redirecionamento e nessa página você executa o código que esta dentro dele.

Nem todos os browsers e versões deles dão suporte a `API` do `LocalStorage`, veja: http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage . Para saber se o browser da suporte ao `LocalStorage` simplesmente teste se ele existe no objeto `window` :

```
if(window.localStorage) {
    // da suporte
} else {
    // não da suporte
}
```

Pra isso você pode fazer a solução usando cookies, veja https://jsfiddle.net/7s4npn3q/2/

Para preservar o código:

HTML

```
<button id="btnJujuba" type="button" src-img-dinamica="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-07/29/10/enhanced/webdr15/enhanced-16875-1438181730-13.jpg">
  jujuba
</button>

<hr />

<img id="imgDinamica" src="http://galaxy.mobity.net/uploads/148/logo/1399898656.png" />
```

JS

```
var btnJujuba = document.querySelector('#btnJujuba');

btnJujuba.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var srcImgDinamica = this.getAttribute('src-img-dinamica');

    document.cookie = 'srcImgDinamica='+srcImgDinamica;

    loadImgDinamica();
});

function loadImgDinamica() {
    var imgDinamica = document.querySelector('#imgDinamica');

    var srcImgDinamica = document.cookie.split('=')[1];

    if(srcImgDinamica) {
        imgDinamica.setAttribute('src', srcImgDinamica);
    }
}
```

Com cookies ja não tem o perigo do browser suportar, porém pra tratar ele ja é mais "complicado" e "manual" pois os cookies não trabalham com "chave e valor" igual o `LocalStorage` então você precisa fazer a busca dentro da `String` registrada no cookie para achar o trecho da informação que você deseja. Talvez transformando um objeto javascript em `JSON` e salvando no cookie, depois fazendo o `parse` dele para objeto javascript de novo melhore o acesso, não testei isso só tive essa idéia agora.

Mas vale uma olhada na documentação sobre cookies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Outra solução também tão manual como usar cookies é usar parâmetro de url, não vou fazer um `jsfiddle` mas fica assim:

JS

```
var btnJujuba = document.querySelector('#btnJujuba');

btnJujuba.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var srcImgDinamica = this.getAttribute('src-img-dinamica');

    window.location.href='http://minhaurl?srcImgDinamica='+encodeURIComponent(srcImgDinamica);
});

// na outra página
function loadImgDinamica() {
    var imgDinamica = document.querySelector('#imgDinamica');

    var srcImgDinamica = getQueryParam().srcImgDinamica;

    if(srcImgDinamica) {
        imgDinamica.setAttribute('src', srcImgDinamica);
    }
}

function getQueryParam() {
    var queryString = {};
    window.location.search.substr(1).split('&').forEach(function (pair) {
      if (pair === '') return;
      var parts = pair.split('=');
      queryString[parts[0]] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1].replace(/\+/g, ' ')).replace(/\+/g, ' ');
    });
    return queryString;
}
```

Essa função `getQueryParam` é uma função que transforma todos os `Query Params` de uma url em um objeto javascript.

Pode-se dizer que a solução por `URL` é a menos sofisticada, por `LocalStorage` a mais sofisticada e a por `Cookie` a intermediária entre elas.

Comment: Caramba Giovani, poxa muito obrigado! Tudo que eu precisava.